# track results of $zip->expandTo in order to log files?

Tags: php, oop, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using the PHP zipArchive class to uncompress files and store them on a server, but I have a couple of problems

extractTo method only returns true or fales, I need a list of the file names and types to that I can

- Check they are valid file types for the function
- Connect the files with database objects for retrieval

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for completeness, the DirectoryIterator is the best way. The process being:

- Create Temp folder
- Extract
- Check with DirectoryIterator class
- Move to Permanent location
- Delete Temp folder

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the class, adding a logging function which then passes through the params to the extractTo method...

see: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: I like the idea, where can I find the original class so I can see how I might begin doing that?

Comment: no idea. AFAIK, all you need to do as far as I know is type "extends foo" and you are good to go: you don't need the original source as the new object will inherit everything from the other object.

Comment: The other option is to just make a base class that mimics all the calls for zipArchive and passes through all paramaters.